Polly boto3 exception: The security token included in the request is invalid
I want to use Amazon Polly with boto3 for TTS with Ssml support.
When I try to run this code, I get the error
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the SynthesizeSpeech operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
import boto3

# AWS credentials
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id='xxx',
    aws_secret_access_key='xxxxx',
    region_name='eu-north-1'
)

# Initialize Polly client
polly_client = session.client('polly')
# Synthesize speech
response = polly_client.synthesize_speech(
    Text='Hello, this is a sample text.',
    OutputFormat='mp3',
    VoiceId='Joanna'  # Specify voice to use
)

# Save synthesized audio to a file
with open('output.mp3', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response['AudioStream'].read())

I checked the keys and if the region is enabled in my account.
I found this but since I didn't download the Aws CLI, I don't have a .aws folder in %USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials.
Do I really need to download and set up the Aws CLI?
Thanks for the help

You don't need to setup the CLI if you specify the credentials in code (like you did). Does the user have the necessary IAM permissions?

I used the wrong login lol. I used the account-id and user-id from the account detailes instead of creating a key.

